# Elasticsearch inconsistent results with large query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm having an issue running an elasticsearch query in production where I am getting inconsistent query results.

Specifically, I have a scenario where I am using pagination using from/to as provided by ES. We are running into a scenario where when we execute a query, we are not getting back an expected result. However, if we run the exact query a second time, we get the expected result back. This inconsistency is causing production level issues for our clients.

I am using a sort order based on a field value that is determined when the document is indexed in order to guarantee pagination consistency. Does anyone have any idea why something like this would be occurring?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I did not get your explanation, but I would not use `from` for pagination, try with the Scroll API:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: `from .. size` should work in general, may you please provide some details like your index mapping and the actual queries that you make? The most awesome would be if it is possible to replicate on some public sample data. May you please also provide details on your deployment, like how many serves, replica count etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the custom [preference setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-preference.html) in a search request. If you use the session id of a web client you can ensure that you are hitting the same shards in subsequent queries.

See also the [definitive guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/_search_options.html#_preference)